# onchange script used in two different function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, onchange

I have here two script. First script used for XMLHttpRequest and the other use for ajax functions for autocomplete. But when I tried to used this script within one page, the XMLHttpRequest isn't working. One of my problem is if XMLHttpRequest not work, the other one will not work also. Any help will appreciate.

```
<select name="cat_code" id="cat_code" type="text" onchange="GetChangedValue(this.value)">
</select>

<script type="text/javascript">
function GetChangedValue(str) {
    if (str==""){
        document.getElementById("item_code").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5   
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){   
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
            document.getElementById("item_code").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
        }   
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getajax.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>

<script>
  function GetChangedValue (val) {
   $( "#items" ).autocomplete({
        selectFirst: true,
            source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON('autocomplete.php?selected='+val, { items: request.term }, response);
  }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: You can't have functons with same name

Comment: @idlerboris what should I do? Because my two script depends on select value with the same dropdownlist

Answer (score 0):

You need to have different names of your functions. Or you can use anonymous functions with jquery in both cases, like this:

```
 $("#cat_code").change(function() { your code } );
```

Or use `on` function, if element appeared dynamically:

```
$(body).on( "change", "#cat_code", function() { your code } )
```

Comment: @idlerbois if I used the your first suggestion, how about the this line? $.getJSON('autocomplete.php?selected='+val, { items: request.term }, response); ? this autocomplete.php?selected='+val,?

Comment: Are you ask "how to get `val` in this case"? `val` you may get by this `val = $(this).val()`

Comment: $("#cat_code").change(function() {
 val = $(this).val();
   $( "#items" ).autocomplete({
  selectFirst: true,
   source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON('autocomplete.php?selected='+val, { items: request.term }, response);
  }
    });
}); like this?

Answer (score 0):

```js
function selCatCodeChange(selVal) {  
  GetChangedValue1(selVal);
  GetChangedValue2(selVal);
}
    
function GetChangedValue1(str) {
  if (str==""){
    document.getElementById("item_code").innerHTML="";
    return;
  }
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)   {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari   
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();  
  } else {
    // code for IE6, IE5   
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  } 
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){   
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
        document.getElementById("item_code").value = xmlhttp.responseText;
    }   
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getajax.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
    
function GetChangedValue2 (val) {
  $( "#items" ).autocomplete({
    selectFirst: true,
    source: function(request, response) {
      $.getJSON('autocomplete.php?selected='+val, { items: request.term }, response);
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="cat_code" id="cat_code" type="text" onchange="selCatCodeChange(this.value)">
</select>
```

The plugin for AutoComplete is either not built correctly or it is not setting the value of the Select to response of the `.autocomplete`

Comment: The plugin for AutoComplete is either not built correctly or it is not setting the value of the Select to response of the `.autocomplete`